# Mongo query with 'like' (regex); extract the field that provide the matching

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking some way for extract the field that provide matching. Example from mongo shell:

```
db.estates.find({$or: [{street: /a/i}, {number: '64'}]}, {street: 1, number: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("551f8b1efec981df83afbaee"), "number" : "123", "street" : "abcd" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("551f8b36fec981df83afbb05"), "street" : "qwer", "number" : "64" }
```

I want to get in results some value pointing to field that provided the matching, or get only this field. Is it real?

Comment: yes because you write in projection only `street` and `number` for more check here 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Comment: if i'll not limit the fields in result i'll get the whole list of fields. But i need only one field, that provide the matching. I was already read link that you gave me and read it again - but not found the answer there.

Comment: because of your find condtions with `or` match both documents, for `street` `abcd` match and for `number`  `64` another record match you should change your query as `db.estates.find({"number": "64"})` it's only find single matching record

Comment: I understand why i get two records in result, and how to manage them. I'm looking some way to get _field_provided_the_match_
For first record it shold be _street_, and _number_ for second record

Comment: No, you'll have to do each query separately, check each result document to see where the match came from, or you could do an aggregation to do the checking and labeling server side. How many results would this query typically return?

Comment: I suppose to get in result about 3-10 records. But this part will be used for autocomplete so queries will come one by the one.